# How to prevent users from viewing settings and permissions on Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Team Foundation Service)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am administering Visual Studio Team Services. I have one DefaultCollection, and one project called Smash.

I wish to add project managers to the project. I want them to be able to manage, edit everything that has to do with project management, i.e. PBIs, Sprints, etc

However, I would like to secure the code entirely so that no project manager has access to, also I would like to prevent them from viewing the settings nor permissions used to secure the code.

I'm using a test account as if it was a project manager. I created a group for project managers, I denied them of ALL permissions except view collection-level (which is essential for them to access the project from the first place)

[image: snapshot of visual studio online collection level settings]

All works fine, i.e. test account can manage PBIs, sprints, etc,  However, the test account could still see the settings and permissions. See below

[image: snapshot of visual studio online settings as seen from test account]

Please help prevent project managers from viewing the settings and permissions used.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would it be a problem for Project Managers to see this info?  (genuinely confused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that you can do. All users who have access to the project have access to view the permissions and settings. As there is no conceivable security risk from this, as they can't change anything, it is available to all.

If you want to have that feature you should sugest it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com...